# Notation about the curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading an paper about geometry, I did not understand the notation (inequality):
$$Rm\geq K$$ 
where k is a real constant and $Rm$ is the curvature tensor. I don't understand what that notation means because $Rm$ is a 4-tensor.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you added a link/reference to the paper

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3255  page 8 Theorem 2.5

Comment: They are saying all the sectional curvatures are bounded below by $K$.

Comment: Are you sure that is was $R_m$ and not $R_{nn}$? The latter would be the $(n,n)$ element of the Ricci curvature. Another possibility is that it is the scalar curvature, and the $m$ is some sort of label rather than an element index.